# Is it possible to configure Google Desktop Search to index data on sharepoint installations?

Tags: sharepoint, google, desktop-management

I would like to be able to use Google Desktop Search to search data that is stored on other computers, as well as my desktop - specifically, data that's stored on a Sharepoint installation on my network. Is it possible to get the Sharepoint install indexed?

Is it also possible to store this index in a central location, and share it with other people that may join the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map the network drive from the server running Sharepoint to your local machine, then yes.

Otherwise, no: Google Desktop is for searching *your* desktop - not the network.

You should look at something like the [Google Search Appliances](http://www.google.com/enterprise/gsa/) or [Mini](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mini/) to meet what you're describing.

Comment: Doesn't a chunk of SharePoint data lives inside an MSSQL database? That won't be indexable even over a drive mapping.

Comment: depends - the sharepoints I've used are over-glorified content containers .. group-protected shares for files and such.. so they're indexable if you map the network drive